# checking/unchecking checkbox list jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, checkboxlist

Please check the below given fiddler.

http://jsfiddle.net/ymtwK/3/

i want to disable all others when one is checked... that is working as expected on the created fiddler. but when i uncheck the already selected one i want want all of them to be enabled...

something is wrong with what my code. please help me to fix it.

i am also wondering if there anything like on unclick event is available...

below is my code..

```
$(".session_outcome_chk_list").click(function () {
    $('.session_outcome_chk_list').each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT:

I also require to do the same on page loads, for example on submitting with selection of one checkbox,  on formload also it should check weather if one is selected or not and then do the disable.

maging a update scenario of a form where u already have one item selected on page load.

#### http://jsfiddle.net/ymtwK/17/

Comment: logic is little wrong
`put alert($(this).is(":checked"));`
before
`if ($(this).is(":checked")) {`
and you will understand

Comment: and also I think `Radio` buttons would be good choice in terms of user experience in your case.

Comment: @SaurabhBayani tnx for the suggestion, actually the issue is this is an already implemented huge system in which i am required to some minor chance which has some impact to other areas..

Comment: Oh ! then you are helpless ;-)  best of luck with that.

Comment: @SaurabhBayani can u help me with this question pls. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096641/jquery-multiple-datepicker-calender-shade-out-from-previous-month-to-this-month

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a single line of code:

```
$('.session_outcome_chk_list').not(this).prop('disabled', this.checked);
```

Also, you should bind the `change()` event, rather than `click()`, so that the code will be executed if the state of the checkbox is changed via a method other than clicking (a keypress, for example).

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymtwK/4/)

---

**Edit:** If you want the code to run when the page is first loaded, just trigger the event after binding it (you'd also have to modify the function in order for it to work properly):

```
$('.session_outcome_chk_list').change(function () {
    $('.session_outcome_chk_list').not(':checked').prop('disabled', !!$('.session_outcome_chk_list:checked').length);
}).change(); // <-- triggers the change event
```

#### [Here's another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymtwK/19/)

Comment: Hi. tnx a lot.. can u pls help me with this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096641/jquery-multiple-datepicker-calender-shade-out-from-previous-month-to-this-month will be a great support.

Comment: please see the edited section of the question. your one is working fine but i want the same to be on page load.

Comment: on load everytime i need to do the same thing. (imaging a update scenario of a form where u already have one item selected on page load)

Comment: @mazraara check my edit, and [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymtwK/19/). You need to modify the function slightly, as pointed out in my edit!

Comment: wooow... many tnx for u.. i cant really believe that it worked... in both scenarios... ur great... btw can u tell if i use click event instead of change event. is that wrong ?

Comment: You can use the click event, the only limitation is that the above code will only be executed when a checkbox is clicked. It won't work if someone checks a checkbox using the keyboard, for example. It'll also fire everytime a checkbox is clicked, whereas change will only fire when the state of the checkbox changes. I'd suggest using change on the basis that it will work for all events (click, keystrokes etc) and will only fire when the state of a checkbox changes.

Comment: i am sorry, the req has been changed by the client and now need to do what we did when only "No answer, Disconnected number & Left message" is selected. i tried modifying the one u suggested and seems not working. i must be missing soemthing. can you pls help me with that ? this is the latest fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ymtwK/19/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34982/discussion-between-mazraara-and-billyonecan)

Answer (score 3):

try this

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ymtwK/5/)

```
$(".session_outcome_chk_list").click(function () {
    var current=$(this);
    if (current.is(":checked")) {
         $('.session_outcome_chk_list').attr("disabled", true);
         current.removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    else {
         $('.session_outcome_chk_list').attr("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

Comment: tnx a lot for u too.. can u pls help me with this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096641/jquery-multiple-datepicker-calender-shade-out-from-previous-month-to-this-month